# Как добавлять строки в массив String[] динамически

Tags: android, строки, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь добавить String в String[] динамически.

Имеется код:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray keys = jsonobject.names();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, Object> map;


String[] str = new String[0];
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); ++i) {
                        String key = keys.getString(i);
                        String value = jsonobject.getString(key);

                        map.put(key, value);

                        str = new String[i + 1];
                        str[i] = key;
                    }
```

Далее настраиваю адаптер

```
jsonAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(EditJsonActivity.this, arrayList, R.layout.json_row_rv,
                        str,
                        new int[]{R.id.idTv, R.id.nameTv, R.id.categoryTv, R.id.pkgnameTv, R.id.imageTv, R.id.urlTv, R.id.url_origTv, R.id.mod_versionTv, R.id.cacheTv, R.id.canmoveTv, R.id.dateTv, R.id.mod_infoTv});
```

Проблема в том, что в массив добавляется только последний ключ. К примеру если взять **map.put(key, value);**, то в map вставляются все ключи.

P.S. программирую не так давно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый раз вызывая строку `str = new String[i + 1];`, вы создаёте новый массив. Но у вас известен размер.

```
String[] str = new String[keys.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); ++i) {
                    String key = keys.getString(i);
                    String value = jsonobject.getString(key);

                    map.put(key, value);

                    str[i] = key;
                }
```